# Java dynamically list allocated objects

Tags: java, object, jvm, runtime, profiler

I'm searching a way to find a list of allocated objects inside the JVM.

I don't want to use a profiler as I want to see these object during runtime, inside the code itself. I wanna create a graph of all objects present inside the program and the interactions between each others.

Do you have a start of a way? I already searched for lots of reflection classes and profilers example but couldn't find something relevant for my case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the source for the garbage collector?  It has to walk the master list of objects each time it collects unused objects.

Comment: *"I wanna create a graph of all objects present inside the program and the interactions between each others."* - that's what profilers do.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this with `JVMTI`. [`GetLoadedClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetLoadedClasses) function is a good entry point

```c
JavaVM *jvm;
jvmtiEnv *jvmti;
jvmtiError err;

env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
jvm->GetEnv((void **) &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_2);

jint classCount = 0;
jclass * classes;

// get all classes loaded by jvm
jvmti->GetLoadedClasses(&classCount, &classes);
```

You can also [traverse heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#Heap) and thus build a graph of objects.

Comment: This looks really powerfull, do you know if there is an equivalent in java? For a future release I wanted to include the graph tool into a Eclipse plugin

Comment: @Jikai well... you can also build instrumentational agent in pure java and try to track allocations by trasforming object constructors like it did [google](https://github.com/google/allocation-instrumenter). but this is very imprecise method and also requires `-javaagent:` paramter (also I'm not sure that you can build whole heap graph with it). with `jni/jvmti` you have to build a native library (actually librart per platform if you want your project to be cross-platform) but you still can pack libs in resources and load on fly

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have a start of a way?

Yes, you can take a heap dump and analyse the heap dump.

Note: use a heap analyser which already exists would be simplest.  e.g. visualvm,  An application can have many millions of objects so a tool designed to do this will help you navigate the data.

Comment: Yes but I want it to be in real time (dynamic) so I don't want to use a dump or a profiler report...